# Can I save a folder's icon as png?

Tags: windows-10, icons, files-folders

I have a folder with a customized icon and I want the customized icon as a PNG file; what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Custom icons can be selected either from an ICO file or from [PE files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable), ie. EXEs and DLLs.

An ICO file can be converted to PNG using your favorite image editor. I think even Paint would work, but in case it doesn't, you can use GIMP, XnView, Photoshop or any online converter (if privacy concerns are not an issue).

If you have selected an icon from a PE file, you should be able to extract it using a resource browser such as [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

If you can't remember anymore which file you've selected for an icon, this preference is saved in a hidden text file called `Desktop.ini` inside the customized folder.

Comment: Oh thanks; I went through folder options and made hidden files visible and inside the folder I wished to save the icon of, I found the ICO file and the ini file of course. Thanks again

Comment: If this answered the question, please feel free to upvote or click the tick to mark as answered. It's this sites way of saying thanks  @solanium